# Why isn't the file modification time changing when writing a partial chunk to it?

Tags: php

I have this test code:

```
function create_file($path, $size_b) {
    $f = fopen($path, "w");
    fseek($f, $size_b - 1, SEEK_CUR);
    fwrite($f, "a");
    fclose($f);
}

function write_file_chunk($path, $offset, $chunk) {
    $f = fopen($path, "r+");
    fseek($f, $offset, SEEK_CUR);
    fwrite($f, $chunk);
    fclose($f);
}

$name = "filemtime_test";
create_file($name, 128);
$m1 = filemtime($name);
sleep(1);
write_file_chunk($name, 0, "hey");
$m2 = filemtime($name);
echo $m1 . " " . $m2 . " " . ($m1 === $m2);
```

The partial write works, I know that but it doesn't seem to change the files modify time, why not? Is there another way I could detect a file was modified in this manner?

Comment: Have you first of all taken into account what the manual for filemtime has to say regarding _caching_?

Comment: oh yea, clearstatcache(); fixes it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance reasons PHP caches this data when such file information functions are called multiple times in the same script instance.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php:

> Note: The results of this function are cached. See [clearstatcache()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) for more details.